# Numpy MemoryError using arange

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy method arange, to create time axis with this parameters

```
import numpy as np
signal =np.ones(626650)
myInterval = 1/125000
t = np.arange(start=0,stop=analogERRN.size-1,step =myInterval, dtype=float)
```

but I am getting an error saying

```
a = np.arange(start=0,stop=analogERRN.size-1,step = 1/125000, dtype=float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LocalData\WPy64-3810\python-3.8.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-fc1514d66d28>", line 1, in <module>
    a = np.arange(start=0,stop=analogERRN.size-1,step = 1/125000, dtype=float)
MemoryError
```

Why is this happening? Can I make use of linespace instead?

Thanks

Comment: How many values do you expect the `arange` to produce?  Is that realistic?  The step is awfully small!

Comment: Well it should `229558` I am working with sampled data...

Comment: 626650*125000 = 78331250000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution using *linspace* function, by creating an equidistant axis and then dividing by the inverse of myInterval ( which is actually the sampling frequency)

```
t = np.linspace(0,len(signal ),len(signal ))/(1/myInterval )
```

Comment: What is `t.shape`?

Comment: it's type `float`